# How to avoid typing in Kendo multi select dropdown

Tags: kendo-ui

I am using `Kendo` `multiselect drop down` but the requirement is to avoid the typing in input box after clicking the dropdown select.I have tried the solutions provided in the link http://www.telerik.com/ but it doesn't work with mac.
My code: -

```
vm.partnerOptions = {
                    animation: RefineBarService.animation,
                    dataSource: vm.partnersData,
                    dataTextField: "id",
                    dataValueField: "id",
                    placeholder: "All Partners",
                    headerTemplate: $compile(angular.element("#partner-header-template").html())($scope),
                    itemTemplate: angular.element("#partner-item-template").html(),
                    tagTemplate: angular.element("#partner-item-template").html()
                };
                vm.owners = res.data.owners;
                vm.reasons = res.data.reasons;});
```

Solution1 tried:-

```
$('input').on('keypress',function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                  })
```

Solution2 tried :-

```
$('.k-input').attr('readonly', "readonly")
```

Comment: This worked for me $('.k-input').prop('readonly', true);

Comment: i tried $('.k-input').prop('readonly', true); it doesn't work.Don't know what mistake i am doing.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me,

```
let ms =  $("#drpMultiSelect").data("kendoMultiSelect");
ms.input.attr("readonly", "readonly");
```